# Cannot reach ethernet login page in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, ethernet

I have a college LAN connection that opens up a login page in my laptop immediately as the LAN cable is inserted into the ethernet port. All was working fine till yesterday's night but since today the **login page is not opening up**, though i'm being shown connected to the wired network.

But when i connect to a wifi network and open Firefox and click on `click here to login to this network` button i'm redirected to a login page and i log-in successfully.

I've come to know that some of my batchmates change their mac addresses and some use VPN ? Could these be of any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` (when you're connected to ethernet). Also, if you go to ebay.com, does the network login page appear? Have you rebooted your computer?

Comment: I have found out the problem ! Actually my laptop's IP address has been blocked for some reason. Is there an easy way to spoof my IP address ?

Comment: You need to talk to your college IT department to solve this.